# How to dynamically set SSLCertificateFile for user's custom domains

Tags: apache, ssl, virtualhost, lets-encrypt

I have a site where users can point their own custom domain to their unique directory on my site through **A Records**.

For example, `example.com` points to `mysite.com/something` and `anothersite.org` points to `mysite.com/somethingelse`

Each of these custom domains has an SSL certificate generated for them however is there a way to point to them dynamically in the VirtualHost file?

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
```

`domain.com` should be the current domain - if someone visits `example.com` then that should be where `domain.com` is.

Is it possible to use variables somehow?

I have tried this but it doesn't work and causes an error:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/%{HTTP_HOST}/fullchain.pem
```

There is one only virtual host in total as there are hundreds of custom domains.

Comment: Well that's what virtual hosts are for. Use them.

Comment: @user207421 So you're saying have a configuration file with thousands of virtual hosts rather than do it dynamically...

Comment: HTTP Host header is not yet sent at the moment when TLS negotiation is happening...

Comment: While Apache could know the domain name (SNI) before the certificate is chosen, it doesn't allow you to dynamically pick the certificate. So using something like `SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/apache/%{HTTP_HOST}.crt` unfortunately doesn't work. Somebody might write a module to do just that.